# How to Connect Java application with Access

Tags: java, odbc, ms-access-2007

I am trying to connect Java application with MS Access 2007
The Connection function is:

```
import java.sql.*;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class ConnectAccess {
    static Connection conn=null;
    public static Connection connectDB(){
        try{
            Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
            conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:history");
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Connection Established");
            return conn;
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

but I am getting this Error message:

> java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] The specified
>   DNS contains an architecture mismatch between Driver and Application

Operating System is Windows 8 64-bit

Comment: Have you tried using a 32bit version of Java?

Comment: No I haven't tried 32-bit version

Comment: There is an Ouse with using a 64bit process to access a 32bit driver (don't ask my whey they're using a 32bit driver) I don't know if it will fix the problem, but that is typically the reason why though...